# Does a low Area Under Curve (AUC) for ROC imply worthless classifier?

Tags: classification, deep-learning, roc, auc

I am trying to do a binary classification (0 and 1), and in this case, the end goal is to maximise the True Positives (i.e. maximum no. of 1s should be predicted correctly, even if it gives rise to significant False Positives). I am obtaining a ROC curve, with Area Under Curve (AUC) for Class 0 being 0.55 and Class 1 being 0.75.

From what I have seen over SE and over the Internet, a value of AUC of 0.75 is a fair value, however, many resources mention that a value in the range 0.50-0.60 etc. might indicate a worthless/random classifier, but I definitely want to maximise the correct predictions for Class 1 instead of losing out on predictions for 1s which may actually belong to 1s. I would like to know that in this case, is the AUC I obtain of any significance, or does it show that the classifier is not useful. Any advice in this regard is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**
The ROC Curve for the problem which I developed in Python is given below.[image]

Comment: The trivial way to maximize TPs is to declare **everything** a positive. Because this observation is completely trivial, I think it's more likely that you really want to find a particular trade-off between TP and FP. Can you shed some light on what your criteria are for a good model, and how this model falls short? Also, what's AUC per class? ROC AUC describes the relative ranks of 2 classes in a single number.

Comment: Usefulness/worthlessness is so context dependent! If I can predict whether a stock will go down or up in the next minute with an AUC of 0.50001 I am a rich man!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please find the updated ROC curve for your kind opinion based on the question.

Comment: @Sycorax please find the updated ROC with the question, and if you could kindly tell if this curve is actually making any sense, as it looks like an elbow shaped one taking a sharp spike somewhere after a particular FPR. Thanks

Comment: @Calimo Thanks for the reply. I now understand that it depends more on the context. But even in that case, (Kindly refer to the updated ROC curve), does this signify that my classifier performs excellently for identifying Class 1. and is just a fail for Class 0. I want to maximise the number of True Positives, even if costs a poor performance for Class 0, but of course, don't want to say that the classifier is just a fail for Class 0. Looking forward to your suggestions!

Comment: You probably have an elbow because you used `predict` instead of `predict_proba` (or similar). But reporting a different ROC AUC for each class doesn't make sense. You'll have to explain what you're doing in more detail for this to be answerable.

Comment: @Sycorax I am using a hybrid model of LSTM-XGBoost for the classification. I used predict_proba only for the purpose of plotting the ROC. I have used scikitplot package to plot the ROCs based on ground truth and the model prediction probabilities (obtained using predict_proba). I'm getting a model accuracy close to 65%, but the scikitplot package's skplt.metrics.plot_roc_curve itself makes this ROC with 2 classes (0 and 1), and I didn't explicitly specify it to make it this way (I think it is an in-built function feature that it plots all classes' ROC together). Thanks

Comment: I haven't used skplt. Maybe the documentation will explain why it's doing this. The plot suggests that all of the predictions are identical for each of the classes. Is that true?

Comment: @Sycorax does it signify that the model is doing better for Class 1 and worse for Class 0? It is true that the False Positive Rate is 0.5955, Precision  0.5886 and, Sensitivity 0.9254 and Specificity 0.4045 alongside the ROC curve. Based on this values, can you kindly interpret whether the model is working for maximising the True Positives, even if it as at the cost of False Positives.Cheers

Comment: I can't say anything about what the plot shows because it has no relationship to any ROC procedure that I've seen before. My comment from yesterday about trivially maximizing true positives remains just as valid now as it was then because you've made no elaboration about what limits, if any, you have for false positives.

Comment: @Sycorax my limit for False Positives is something which should not be more than 60% of the cases. If the True Positives are correctly identified for greater than 90% of cases (which is the case now), I am very satisfied with the model, even though it may lead to a lower overall accuracy as such (which is why the accuracy is 65 %). This is the very tradeoff, but of course, not to ensure that the classifier is either a random one or just biased. Because, these are just based on the actual results at the moment. Your comments are interesting, and I've upvoted all of them.Cheers.

Comment: @Sycorax my only final query to you again, is that whether this is a good example for maximising True Positives even at the cost of False Positives (as I said the limit being 60%)? I know in Medicine and other domain, often it is better to diagnose an unhealthy patient, than actually leaving one out. Would like your final opinion please.

Comment: Whether it's good or bad depends on the context. If your test is incorrect, and you say a patient is ill and needs to have his foot amputated, that's a terrible outcome. If your test is incorrect, and the patient takes an unnecessary dosage of vitamin C, the consequences are much less severe.

Comment: @Sycorax I got it. So, in my case, I am looking for a person to go and repair a machine if there is a fault alarm. In this scenario, I believe it is better to actually check the faults in advance, even if it may increase the costs associated. It is probably better to spot the problem, than leave it out. So now, as this is the context, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @JChat you should edit your question to contain these extra information.